# How to hide/show meta box using jQuery,if click on Drop-Down Menu

Tags: metabox, dropdown

I'm newbie with jQuery and try to add a text field dynamically to the admin(New post) using jQuery.

For example,only if I click on 'Other' from the Drop-Down selection menu - the text field is visible.
Here is my 'attempt':

**jQuery**:

```
 jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  jQuery('#prefix-nums').bind('change', function (e) { 
  if( jQuery('#prefix-nums').val() == 'other') {
   $('#prefix-text-1').show();
    jQuery("#prefix-text-1").css({ display: "inline-block" });
  }else if( $('#prefix-nums').val() == 'first') {
  jQuery('#prefix-text-1').hide();  
  }).trigger('change');
  });
```

**Functions.php**

```
$prefix = 'prefix-';
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'untitled',
    'title' => esc_html__( 'Some nums', 'metabox-online-generator' ),
    'post_types' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'context' => 'advanced',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'autosave' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id' => $prefix . 'nums',
            'name' => esc_html__( 'nums', 'metabox-online-generator' ),
            'type' => 'select_advanced',
            'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Select an Item', 'metabox-online-generator' ),
            'options' => array(
                'one' => 'one',
                'two' => 'two',
                'three' => 'three',
                'four' => 'four',
                'other' => 'other',

            ),
            'class' => 'numbers',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => $prefix . 'text-1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Other nums', 'metabox-online-generator'),
            'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Other nums', 'metabox-online-generator' ),
            'class' => 'text-1',
        ),
```

And of course..that just not work ^^....

Can you help me?Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,

Comment: First of all `bind` has been deprecated since jquery 3.0. Use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach events.

And please explain what's not working? is it giving any error? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I have also written a [gist](https://gist.github.com/digvijayad/7657037be67c90220f7b3bcec8baccc1) that shows the meta box only when you select a specific category. Perhaps you'll get some idea on what to do.

Comment: Thank you.@Digvijayad actually - yes: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) by:  }).trigger('change');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a `syntax error` which means that you are typing something incorrectly. Use the following jQuery to show/hide meta with the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method,

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, `bind` has been deprecated since jQuery 3.0. It is now recommended to use `.on()` method.

Note: You can use the shorthand `$` instead of writing `jQuery` every time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 $('#prefix-nums').on('change', function(e) {

   if ($(this).val() == 'other') {
     $('#prefix-text-1').show();
     $("#prefix-text-1").css({
       display: "inline-block"
     });
   } else if ($(this).val() == 'first') {
     $('#prefix-text-1').hide();
   }

  });
});
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/digvijayad/u9njvjsr/1/)

And Here is a nice free [jQuery](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery) Course that takes about 3 hours

Comment: I've one more question:How can be this field hidden by default ?Maybe $('#prefix-text-1').hide before the if-statement ? ** Update **

Comment: @DeanTwit place `$('#prefix-text-1).hide()` before the `.on()` event handler, Or you can use `#prefix-text-1{display: none;}` in the css.